# namespace name= other name

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was reading the code of a file in the tutorial of MoveIt Ros melodic and I saw this
namespace rvt = rviz_visual_tools;

and it doesn't make sense for me, someone want to explain to me that

note: code line 82

https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_tutorials/blob/melodic-devel/doc/move_group_interface/src/move_group_interface_tutorial.cpp

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369215/namespace-name=-other-name/) by [RDLUIS](https://answers.ros.org/users/67616/rdluis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-01-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RDLUIS](https://answers.ros.org/users/67616/rdluis/) on 2021-01-12**:
that line code is in line 82

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's just so you can type `rvt::whatever()` instead of `rviz_visual_tools::whatever()` without losing some connection to the fact that `whatever()` comes from `rviz_visual_tools`(and avoiding name collisions which I'd guess is likely here with the MoveIt visual tools, but I'd have to dig in the code to be sure.)

You know [here for example](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_tutorials/blob/melodic-devel/doc/move_group_interface/src/move_group_interface_tutorial.cpp#L141) that `WHITE` and `LARGE` come from `rviz_visual_tools` which otherwise would be hard to know at a glance at that line.

With the [namespace alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias), it's easy to see.

---

Originally posted by [qTHqq](https://answers.ros.org/users/66674/qthqq/) with karma: 26 on 2021-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RDLUIS](https://answers.ros.org/users/67616/rdluis/) on 2021-01-13**:
thank you very much you're the best